# Store data in PostgreSQL using Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and would like to know more about it, so I tried [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbq2CAHNRZM&t=1903s). I followed all code but cannot store data in the database and I get this error:

[image: error]

TodoController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $todo = Todo::create($request->all());
    $todo->create();
    return $todo;
}
```

Post.php

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'completed'];
```

TodoComponent.vue

```
<form @submit.prevent="saveData">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input v-model="form.title" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Add List </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Vue method

```
methods:{
    saveData(){
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('title', this.form.title)
        axios.post('/api/todo', data)
    }
},
```

Comment: welcome to SO ... `saveData()` is in same component ?

Comment: yes same component in methods:

Comment: add full code of `TodoComponent.vue`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CisEWhBz

Comment: run `npm run watch` your code is correct

Comment: during development I always run

Comment: In your pastebin, `new Form` is not a function. It should just be a plain object

Comment: how to solve that?